# Jinja2 Unicode in Python 3

Tags: python, pandas, jinja2

I have a pandas dataframe that contains unicode characters. I have confirmed that the data type is "str" for the fields in question, which should be unicode in Python 3.

Jinja2 specifies that it should be sent Unicode, and I am passing this unicode df to template.render.

https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/api/#unicode

The rendered webpage contains the diamond question mark character in place of the unicode character.

Edit: I included the meta charset="utf-8" in my html head.

Any ideas on what is happening?

Comment: Supposing that you are loading the strings from your db to your web server correctly (have you confirmed this?), you should put together a Minimum Reproducible Example. This is tricky for a web server, but the least you could do is show the web server app code. Is this Flask?

Comment: For now I am writing a static page to a file. I then open it in Chrome. Sqlite3 is my database and seems to say that it is utf-8. The pd dataframe is made from it. I didn't know how to do an example without including the suspect files/db.

Comment: Great. So then you can use Python to query the unicode entries in the SQLite3 DB. And also query the unicode entries in the Pandas DB that is generated from that. Show your queries and the output. Then show your code to generate the static web page (the relevant excerpt) and show the web page that is generated (excerpt). A screenshot of the web page opened in Chrome too (or better, put it in jsfiddle).

Comment: You helped me solve it. In my simple test case, I didn't think about the encoding when writing the file. I fixed it by setting the encoding when opening the output file. This would all have been so much easier on a server. Thanks for the nudge!

Comment: Quack quack quack! You're welcome.